# Generate csv file on user request in google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, csv

I have the requirement to download the user reports (read from the datastore) in the form of csv file when user click on the download opton.

As i am knowing that we are not create/store the files in the google app engine server. So how to generate the reports in the csv.

Is there any way to do this.

Please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple. You need to generate the CSV file on-the-fly and then serve it to the user. So I imagine you will create a way to direct a CSV request, which instead of normal HTML output would generate the requested CSV file. You will also need to ensure that the headers are correct.

Similar issue has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128941/writing-to-csv-files-and-then-zipping-it-up-in-appengine-java).

Answer (score 0):

You can save data in the blobstore and download the blob.