# Serialize a class to json in diffrent ways

Tags: java, json, serialization

Is there any way to serialize a class into json but only with fields I want to use in particular case without need of creating multiple variations of class?
Let's take an example:

```
class User{

    @JsonField
    private String name;

    @JsonField
    private String surname;

    @JsonField
    private String hashedCode;

    @JsonField
    private String city;

    @JsonField
    private String anotherDummyString;
}
```

Now in one of my methods I would like to have a mapping to json Object which only contains **name**, **city** and **anotherDummyString**.

In Second method I want to have **surname** and **city**. In third method ... .

Is there any pleasant and neat way to achive this? 
I was wondering if I can "hide" these fields which I don't need.

Comment: You are right, my mistake, updated post

Comment: Whether the JSON serializer can do this depends entirely on *which* JSON library you're using, don't you think?

Comment: See [Serialize Only Fields that meet a Custom Criteria with Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include only specific properties when serializing with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26509033/5221149), or [How do I exclude fields with Jackson not using annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13764280/5221149)

Comment: Which library are you using to do the serialization/deserialization? Can any library be used for a valid answer?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? (Using javax.json)

```
JsonObject getJson1() {
    return Json.createObjectBuilder().add("name", this.name).add("city", this.city).build();
}
JsonObject getJson2() {
    return Json.createObjectBuilder().add("surname", this.surname).add("city", this.city).build();
}
```

Just `.add` what you need in each function call.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for a kind of filter for your fields in Class

This can be achieved using Jackson @JsonFilter

```
package com.concretepage;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFilter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonFilter("student")
public class Student 
{
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("surname")    
    private String surname;

    @JsonProperty("hashedCode") 
    private String hashedCode;

    @JsonProperty("city")   
    private String city;

    @JsonProperty("anotherDummyString") 
    private String anotherDummyString;

}
```

Create a simple filter for you above class

```
SimpleFilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider();
filterProvider.addFilter("student",
        SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("name", "city","anotherDummyString"));
```

Set it to a object mapper

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setFilterProvider(filterProvider);
```

To get the json message

```
//Pass the student object  
String jsonData = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
               .writeValueAsString(student);
```

You must able to have you 2 variance of class by creating one more sample filter like above