# Using a data sheet to create objects in realtime

Tags: xml, database, superclass

I'm actually really new to java. I've noticed a lot of people take on a similar task, but I can't seem to find the answer I think I'm looking for.
I'm making a very simple Pokemon game (learning purposes). Long story short, my question is about handling the abundant amount of creatures/characte0rs/objects(?) that need to be created.

The technique I've been using is with a pokemon superclass with setters and getters. Was wondering about xml files to store the list of 150 different pokemon (each with different attribute values, but all with the same set of attributes). But it seems like that involves a lot of coding as well. I like that I can also create a class to read and write the xml file, to recieve data and potentially create/change data as well.

BUT, I've seen use of a list-like sheet that basically looks something like:

`Pikachu,12,30,20,15,Thunder Bolt,Quick Attack,electric,none,etc...`

`Bulbasaur, 20,52,16,Leech Seed,Growl,plant,fire,etc...`

`(name,atk,def,speed,move1,move2,type,weakness,etc...)`

Where the different attributes of the object(pokemon) are stored in a line seperated by commas. If i understand correctly, these attributes are then read by a method that needs very little coding to read the whole line, and then plugs in the values on the line to their proper variable in the object without having to restate the name of each variable.

Im a complete java noob, sorry if this is completly wrong. Im really just curious what this technique is called and where i can find resources for learning it. If it's even a viable option for what im doing. Also curious if this technique(datasheet?) is capable of being edited by java like xml is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're talking about a `csv` file. This is just a different way to save your data. This stands for comma separated value. It's just basically a table, usually with the first row specifying the field name with each line as a record (or object) after that. A good exercise would be to write both `csv` and `xml` readers and writers.

Comment: Wow! That was fast. Thank you so much. So the 'csv' files CAN be edited through a Java built writer? Just like the 'xml'? The 'csv' option seems like a faster way to write out a large amount of values. Although, the 'xml' seems easier to read since everything is labeled within child tags.

Comment: Would I still need getters and setters, and a pokemon superclass? I'm assuming yes. The readers would just read the 'csv' file and hand off the info to the constructor.... right? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Well, I'd say the big difference is that `csv`s should really only be used for tables of data, where each object has the same number of attributes. `xml` has the benefit of a tree structure that allows different number of attributes, or branches, as well as sub-branches with many layers

Comment: Fair enough. In this case all pokemon share the same set of attributes but with different values. So I guess csv would work just fine. Seems like xml has some far-reaching capabilities though. I'm primarily a game designer. More on the art side than anything else. But my interest in coding has been growing. Trying to think when i'd use xml. I guess for something like a skill tree. Where you have different branches and sub branches of each skill the player can learn....

Thanks again for the help @bnjmn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are referring to is a `csv` file which stand for comma separated value. There are many existing methods for reading and writing these files in just about any programming language, including Java. `csv` is a very common structure for storing data that is in a table format, meaning there are rows and columns. Generally, each row represents a record, or object in your case, and is expected to have the same number of fields, or attributes in your case. The first line typically states the field names, but sometimes this provided separately.

`xml` allows for hierarchical data. Maybe you don't know how many `moves` each pokemon will have, some might have 1 and others could have as many as 5 for example. `xml` might be a better choice in this case.

I recommend implementing both if you can to see which one works better as a learning experience. Also, this sounds like a great opportunity to learn about [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29). Check out [this Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) on it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will most definitely try out both methods and the tutorial you've linked me to. This is simply a learning exercise for me. I have no intention on going through with implementing all 150 original pokemon. I simply wanted to better understand the more efficient ways to code a large database. I will probably do about 25-50 pokemon in the various methods you've mentioned till I feel I've completely grasped the concept. I just started on my own 4 days ago on my spare time, and started to feel really lost. I seriously appreciate the quick feedback. It's been enlightening.

Comment: No problem. It can be overwhelming sometimes but keep at it; there's no better way to learn than by doing. It sounds like you already have a great start. Feel free to accept the answer if you did find it useful.

Comment: A thought just occurred to me. 
The csv is required to have the same number of values on each line right? 
What if one of the values is set to 'null'.... will that return null in java and basically shut that value off?
Some pokemon have 2 types. Most have one. Can I put 
>'type1,null,etc
in my csv. and will that return null to java safley?

Comment: That is absolutely an option that should be handled by the `csv` parser you implement. [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3666052/770019) of someone writing an object to a `csv`. You should be able to follow it and get an idea of how you might go the other way to read it back in.