# Export dynamic data from a JSP page to CSV in Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, csv, struts2

I am trying to implement a function in which a user downloads a file in a `CSV` format. I have done the downloading part and I am able to convert the `JSP` to `CSV` format but the issue that I am facing is that I am unable to transfer the dynamic data from the `JSP` to `CSV` file. After downloading the file I see the `JSP tags` and all other contents of it instead I want to see the data only, not the `JSP tags` or `forms` etc.

Actions Class:

```
public String viewReport() throws Exception {
    boolean returnReport;

    String filePath = "fileName.jsp";

    File file = new File(filePath);
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

    try {
        returnReport = validateRequest();
        if (returnReport) {
            setIntgList(generateViewIntegrationReportData(getESignUIConfig()));
        } else {
            failureResponse(msgs, 400);
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        msgs.add(new Message(ESignatureIntegrationMessageTypeEnum.MESSAGE_TYPE_ERROR, 
                    UiIntegrationKeyConstants.UI_INTEGRATION_ERROR_CODE_500, UiIntegrationKeyConstants.UI_INTEGRATION_ERROR_TEXT_SERVICE_ERROR));
        failureResponse(msgs, 500);
        return null;
    }

    return UiIntegrationKeyConstants.INTEGRATION_DETAILS_REPORT_REPSONSE;
}
```

JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/integration.tld" prefix="integration" %>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<integration:file  name="integration.css" type="CSS" prefix="/esign/styles/"/>'/>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<integration:file  name="integration.js" type="JS" prefix="/esign/scripts/integration/"/>">
</script>
<h1><center>Transaction Report Page</center></h1>
<br></br>
<c:forEach items="${intgList}" var="list">
        <tr class="<%=count % 2 != 0 ? "odd" : "even"  %>">
            <td class="dataFieldCell1" align="center"><c:out  value="${list.lob}" /></td>
            <td class="dataFieldCell1" align="center"><c:out value="${list.insuredName}" /></td>
            <td class="dataFieldCell1" align="center"><c:out value="${list.custPhone}" /></td>
             <c:if test="${list.policyNbrLink eq true}">
                <td class="dataFieldCell1" align="center"><a href='#x' style="text-decoration:none" onclick="locateFunc('viewESignPolicyDetails',
                                                                                                                    {'agencyCode':'${list.agencyCode}',
                                                                                                                     'policyNumber':'${list.policyNumber}',
                                                                                                                     'policyState':'${list.policyState}',
                                                                                                                     'esignIdentifier':'${list.esignId}',
                                                                                                                     'esignVendorIdentifier':'${list.esignVendorIdentifier}',
                                                                                                                     'transId':'${list.transId}',
                                                                                                                     'lob':'${list.lob}',
                                                                                                                     'customerName':'${list.insuredName}',
                                                                                                                     'customerPhone':'${list.custPhone}',
                                                                                                                     'customerEmail':'${list.custEmail}',
                                                                                                                     'cretedDate':'${list.createdDate}'}
                                                                                                                    )"><c:out value="${list.policyNumber}"/></a></td>
            </c:if> 
            <c:if test="${list.policyNbrLink eq false}">
                <td class="dataFieldCell1" align="center"><c:out value="${list.policyNumber}"/></td>
            </c:if>
            <td class="dataFieldCell1" align="center"><c:out value="${list.createdDate}" /></td>
            <td class="dataFieldCellWrap" align="center"><c:out value="${list.custEmail}" /></td>
             <td class="dataFieldCell1" align="center"><a href='#x' onclick="locateFunc('viewESignDetails',
                                                                     {'url':'<integration:urlAction actionName="/integration/viewDetailsIntegration"><integration:urlParam key="esignIdentifier" value="${list.esignId}"/></integration:urlAction>',
                                                                     'agencyCode':'${list.agencyCode}',
                                                                     'policyNumber':'${list.policyNumber}',
                                                                     'policyState':'${list.policyState}',
                                                                     'esignIdentifier':'${list.esignId}',
                                                                     'esignVendorIdentifier':'${list.esignVendorIdentifier}',
                                                                     'lob':'${list.lob}',
                                                                     'transId':'${list.transId}',
                                                                     'customerName':'${list.insuredName}',
                                                                     'customerPhone':'${list.custPhone}',
                                                                     'customerEmail':'${list.custEmail}',
                                                                     'cretedDate':'${list.createdDate}'}
                                                                    )"><c:out value="${list.esignNumDocs}"/></a></td> 
        </tr>
        <%count++;%>
    </c:forEach>
```

Struts.xml

```
<action name="*Integration" method="{1}" class="classPath">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">integrationView</result> 
        <result name="integrationDetailsReportResponse" type="stream">
            <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
            <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
            <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="integrationReportDetailsView.csv"</param>
            <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
        </result>   
</action>
```

There are some similar questions but they are confusing and I was unable to relate them to my need so please don't duplicate it.

Comment: I did a research and the configuration in Struts.xml should take care of everything but it is not displaying the data. It displays the raw jsp content only. Do you have any ideas around that?

Comment: You cannot export jsp to csv, obviously. (But you can export view to pdf with the help of S2 plugin.) If you need csv then create it on server and stream back to user.

Comment: Please take a look at `OpenCSV` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why no one answered this question and I think the question wasn't that hard. So in order to get the dynamic data from a `JSP` to a `CSV` file format we need to `Serialize` our `Java Object` to `CSV` format. There are some `libraries` that can used to achieve this goal. I used `OpenSCV` and passed my `POJO` into it. Now when I click on the button, i can not only download the file but I am also getting the data from `JSP` to a `CSV`. What I was missing was the `Serializing` part of Object.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666007/how-to-serialize-object-to-csv-file) link may help someone.

Comment: This is not jsp to csv.

Comment: A JSP isn't a POJO. Can you share an example of how did you pass the processed JSP to the OpenSCV serializer? Sounds interesting but i can't imagine a way to do that.

Comment: In JSP through Spring Expression language you can display the data right. So instead of displaying it over there download the file as CSV using Struts2 serialize POJO or java bean or in very simple wording a simple java class using OpenCSV.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood, but what you are trying to do is not possible.

You put your fileName.jsp into a InputStream and download it as integrationReportDetailsView.csv? Of course you cant get the dinamic content of the jsp, what you are doing is similar to download the file using a FTP server for example.

The dinamic content of the jsp is created by the server when you make a request but you aren't calling to the jsp, you are calling to an action that downloads the binary data of the file and sending it as an attachment. The server never processes it so the jsp tags are not evaluated and the dinamic content is not created.

Comment: fileName.jsp is the same file that I am downloading. I didn't want to show the absolute path of it. So to show the dynamic data, the file has to be processed in the server.