# XSteream Java Obj to XML Skipping some of the fields

Tags: java, xml, object, xstream

How to skip certain fields of object in serialization of Obj to XML.

code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143234/serializing-java-objects-to-xml-with-xstream)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Xtream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/faq.html)

> How do I specify that a field should
>   not be serialized?
>
> Make it transient, specify it with
>   XStream.omitField() or annotate it
>   with @XStreamOmitField

Try www.google.com

Answer (score 1):

Mark the fields to skip with the 'transient' keyword. Example based on your code:

```
public class Foo 
{
    public transient int a;
    public String b;
    public Bar boo;

    public Foo(int a, String b, Bar c)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.boo = c;
    }
}
```

The property a will not be serialized to XML.